# nohup: can't execute 'display_files.sh': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I want to run my code with
`nohup shellskriptname &`. But whenever I try to see the `nohup`, it says there is no such file. What can I do, so I can enter it like that?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# To Display Files and Folders from current Directory

echo Displaying all the Directories in the current directory

for item in *
do
        if [ -d $item ]
         then
                echo $item
        fi
done

echo Displaying all the Files in the current directory

for item in *
do
        if [ -f $item ]
        then
                echo $item
        fi
done
```

Comment: Did you run `chmod +x display_files.sh`? Your script requires execute permissions.

Comment: Hello, yes it is -rwxrwsrwx

Comment: Then perhaps the CWD is not in the PATH, and it needs to be called with ./display_files.sh`.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show the command you type where invoking the script works, and the `nohup` command you type where invoking the script fails?  And also include the error message that you get from the failing command.

Comment: Where should I enter this in my code?

Comment: This is the code I type. On AIX on ksh it always works like this `nohup display_files.sh &`

Comment: @Eronsee are you on AIX or Linux? You've tagged with [tag:Linux] but you've mentioned AIX and `ksh`.

Comment: I am currently on Linux

Comment: You should [double-quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) when you use them. So instead of `if [ -d $item ]` you should write `if [ -d "$item" ]`, etc.

Comment: Also be aware that `echo $item` is not robust - consider a file called `-n`, for example. Instead, use `printf '%s\n' "$item"`

Comment: Ok, but I think it doesn't solve the problem? running my code without the double-quotes works with ./display_files.sh. Do you agree it is a path problem?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't provided an exact error, just a paraphrase. For example it might have come from running the code. Pleaes provide the exact command you're running and the precise error message, and where you see it.

Comment: works with your recommendation but not with nohup still :(  ``` 
#!/usr/bin/bash

# To Display Files and Folders from current Directory


echo Displaying all the Directories in the current directory


for item in *
do
        if [ -d "$item" ]
         then

                printf '%s\n' "$item"
        fi

done


echo Displaying all the Files in the current directory


for item in *
do

        if [ -f "$item" ]
        then

                printf '%s\n' "$item"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Running like this: nohup display_files.sh & Error in the nohup.out: nohup: can't execute 'display_files.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: @Eronsee, if the current working directory is not in you path, then you need to give the path to the command, either relative or absolute. It's not `nohup display_files.sh`, it's `nohup ./display_files.sh` I think you are missing `./`.

Comment: Eronsee please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/713711/edit) to include new information. It's way too easy to miss it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Whether you run your script with or without `nohup`, the shell will try to locate the named command (your script) in the directories listed in `$PATH`.  It will do this unless you specify the name of your script with a directory path (either absolute or relative).

From the manual of `nohup` on my current FreeBSD system, regarding the utility's use of the `PATH` environment variable:

> `PATH`
> Used to locate the requested utility if the name contains no `/`
> characters.

This means `nohup`, just like the shell, would look up the given utility in `$PATH` if the command contains no directory path.

So, if your script, `shellskriptname`, is located in the current directory and if the current directory is not one of the directories in `$PATH`, then using just

```bash
shellskriptname
```

or

```bash
nohup shellskriptname
```

would fail in the way that you describe.

Instead, give the path to the script:

```bash
nohup ./shellskriptname
```

Add `&` at the end of the command if you need to run the command as an asynchronous job ("background job").

Regarding the actual script, please see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)